# How do I create an empty file in emacs?

Tags: file, emacs, elisp, dired

How can I create an empty file from emacs, ideally from within a dired buffer?

For example, I've just opened a Python module in dired mode, created a new directory, opened that in dired, and now need to add an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory.

If I use `C-x C-f __init__.py RET C-x C-s` then emacs doesn't create the file because no changes have been made to it.  I would have to type in the file, save it, delete my typing and then save it again for that to work.

Thanks

Comment: I live with this deadlock: Emacs is a powerful text editor which can even integrate a Scala compiler, etc, etc ... but many times very simple things are overcomplicated. I find easier to "touch /path/to/filename" and later open it in Emacs than trying to create a new file inside Emacs, in particular when there's another file with the same name or even a similar name. Emacs "tries to help me" opening the wrong file. Please, do not "try to help me!"... just do what I told you that should be done! I'm pretty sure there must be a "plugin" (maybe dired) which does that. Overcomplicated! again!

Comment: @RichardGomes Having been using phils's solution for a couple of years now, I'm finding it much easier to just type "_" and it asks me for a file name. Emacs is definitely very complicated, but I don't think it's over-complicated.  Much of what I've done to it over the last 5 years has been to make it more complicated, as well as shaving off all those annoying corners.  I suffered from exactly the same problem with the completion as you, but it is fixable if you can be bothered to spend a few years getting to know the system.

Comment: `C-x C-f __init__.py RET C-x C-s` works fine for me (version `24.5.1`), so maybe the issue has been resolved since this question was originally asked.

Comment: You're right it does seem to have been fixed.  And the nice thing is, it works anywhere, even when you aren't in dired.  These days I've bound `C-x j` to open dired, and then `_` to create a new file, which is pretty short

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of `dired-create-directory`. It works the same way, so as well as a plain filename, you can also specify new parent directories (to be created under the current directory) for the file (e.g. `foo/bar/filename`).

```el
(eval-after-load 'dired
  '(progn
     (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-c n") 'my-dired-create-file)
     (defun my-dired-create-file (file)
       "Create a file called FILE.
If FILE already exists, signal an error."
       (interactive
        (list (read-file-name "Create file: " (dired-current-directory))))
       (let* ((expanded (expand-file-name file))
              (try expanded)
              (dir (directory-file-name (file-name-directory expanded)))
              new)
         (if (file-exists-p expanded)
             (error "Cannot create file %s: file exists" expanded))
         ;; Find the topmost nonexistent parent dir (variable `new')
         (while (and try (not (file-exists-p try)) (not (equal new try)))
           (setq new try
                 try (directory-file-name (file-name-directory try))))
         (when (not (file-exists-p dir))
           (make-directory dir t))
         (write-region "" nil expanded t)
         (when new
           (dired-add-file new)
           (dired-move-to-filename))))))
```

Comment: Although I've specified a user-reserved binding in the code, I've actually bound this to `_` which on my keyboard layout is the shifted sequence next to `+`, meaning the keys for "new directory" and "new file" in dired are right next to one another.

Comment: I've changed this to be the answer, as it is the one that I'm using in the long term.

Answer (score 62):

You can use the touch command:

```
M-! touch __init__.py RET
```

Comment: @offby1, if you add that as a proper answer, I'll choose it, as that's the one that works best for me.  It even uses whatever directory dired is in as the cwd.

Comment: I like that very much, too! I just don't like typing the M-! bit, but I guess I can change the keybinding  :)

Comment: Using touch this way will might be effected by the default-directory variable which means it might not be the directory shown in the dired buffer.  I ran into this since I sue .dir-locals.el in root which I find to set default-directory.  Instead I just bound C-x C-f to a function that uses `make-empty-file` immediately followed by a `revert-buffer` (which in dired-mode will just refresh with the newly added file).

Answer (score 29):

The following works:

```
C-x b __init__.py RET C-x C-w RET
```

If you're in a dired buffer the file will be saved in the directory show here.

The trick is to first create an empty buffer by switching to a name that doesn't exist. Then write out the file.

Comment: This method is great because it creates a new file, warns if it exists already and ends with the new file in an open buffer. This matches 99% of my use cases.

Comment: In my set up, if the file name matches another one in its buffer history, then C-x b will open that file instead of new one. This is handy, except in cases where you want to create a new file, or you have multiple ones that have the same name (__init__.py would be one of those).

Answer (score 20):

If you want Emacs to treat all new files as modified, you can automate the solution like this:

```el
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'assume-new-is-modified)
(defun assume-new-is-modified ()
  (when (not (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name)))
    (set-buffer-modified-p t)))
```

Comment: I like this, and I think I'll probably set it anyway, because it seems a saner in the general case, but the `M-! touch __init__.py` is shorter and doesn't involve opening and closing a buffer.

Comment: @Singletoned - you don't have to enter this every time. Just put it in your init file and every time you create a new file with `C-x C-f` it will show up in dired. That's quicker than typing out a shell command (`touch`) every time.

Comment: What do you mean "treat as modified"?

Answer (score 15):

Programatically and without any dependency on `touch`, it's quite easy:

```
(with-temp-buffer (write-file "path/to/empty/file/"))
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer for emacs 26.

Answer (score 14):

After this thread, Emacs has added two new commands:

1. make-empty-file
2. dired-create-empty-file

These commands will be available in the emacs 27.1 release.

Comment: And that's what `make-empty-file` is using to make the empty file: `(write-region "" nil filename nil 0)`

Comment: Years (many years) ago emacs "New file" tab just did this: Open a window *without* necessity of a filename. "Nice" they got somehow back to this (better! imho) way.

Answer (score 12):

Emacs won't allow you to save a buffer unless it thinks the contents have changed. The quickest, though possibly not cleanest is to open the file using <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>, then press (say) space and backspace, then you should be able to save a file with no contents.

There are other ways of changing the "buffer has been modified" flag, but I don't think there's any easier.

Answer (score 6):

Use touch command.

```
M-! touch __init__.py RET
```

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way

Creates an empty file via a shell operation (but does not open it):

<kbd>M-!</kbd> `> __init__.py` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Open the new file:

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

(Note: we don't have to type in the name again, because the new file is automatically the first choice)

Comment: That's quite clever, and definitely shorter than using touch.  Though the solution I'm using is @phils which makes it just `_` followed by `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 3):

`(shell-command (concat "touch " (buffer-file-name)))` will do what you want, if you've already opened the empty file.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers on the page, you can use [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el)'s function [`f-touch`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-touch-path):

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`(f-touch "__init__.py")`<kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can mark an empty buffer as modified by running [`set-buffer-modified-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Modification.html). Then when you save it, Emacs will write the file.

```
M-;                         ; Eval
(set-buffer-modified-p t)   ; Mark modified
C-x C-s                     ; Save buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following bound to `t` in dired.

```
(defun my-dired-touch (filename)
  (interactive (list (read-string "Filename: " ".gitkeep")))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (write-file filename)))

;; optionally bind it in dired
(with-eval-after-load 'dired
  (define-key dired-mode-map "t" 'my-dired-touch))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified answer from MrBones and created custom function with keybinding:

```
; create empty __init__.py at the place
(defun create-empty-init-py()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "touch __init__.py")
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p i") 'create-empty-init-py)
```

This is very useful to not spend time on recurring action of creating **init**.py everywhere in new Python project folder.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be:

```
(with-temp-file "filename"
  (insert ""))
```