# How to create an empty file by elisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I set an explicit file to customization created via the UI. It's named `custom.el`. Currently, I use the followed snippets to create this file if not exist.

```
(defconst custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))
(unless (file-exists-p custom-file)
  (shell-command (concat "touch " custom-file)))
```

There is an ugly shell-command `touch` in, any other elisp functions can do this?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2592095/596361

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `(write-region "" nil custom-file)` not sure that is the ideal solution.

Comment: If you change the first `nil` to `""`, then you'd have the ideal solution, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a simpler solution to the underlying problem would be:

```
(defconst custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))
;; NOERROR to ignore nonexistent file - Emacs will create it
(load custom-file t)
```

In other words, instead of manually creating `custom.el`, simply don't error when you try to load it (optional arg `NOERROR` is only for file existence error). Emacs will create the file the first time it writes out custom variables.

This is what I'm currently using in my `init.el`

Answer (score 1):

```el
(make-empty-file custom-file)
```

Check help to know more about it: `C-h f make-empty-file`

Comment: Seems to be a newer function; Emacs 26.3 doesn't have it but Emacs 28.1 does.

Answer (score 0):

I write this function below based on Joao Tavara anwser in this post: [How do I create an empty file in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592095/how-do-i-create-an-empty-file-in-emacs)

```
(defun fzl-create-empty-file-if-no-exists(filePath)
   "Create a file with FILEPATH parameter."
   (if (file-exists-p filePath)
       (message (concat  "File " (concat filePath " already exists")))
     (with-temp-buffer (write-file filePath))))
```