# How to use function `write-region`?

Tags: file, emacs

I try to make a new file, according to this question and answer: [How to create an empty file by elisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071991/how-to-create-an-empty-file-by-elisp)

I copied the code

```
(write-region "" nil custom-file)
```

into a new emacs file and wanted to execute it by C-x C-e. But all i get is

```
 Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

So what am i doing wrong here ? Im pretty new to emacs and have tried finding a solution by googling it but had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the value of `custom-file` is `nil`.  It should be a string (that names a file).

If you set variable `debug-on-error` to `t` then you'll get a backtrace that will show you which arg that was expected as a string is actually `nil`.

Try wrapping your (relative) file name in expand-file-name, like this:

```
(write-region "" nil (expand-file-name "new_file"))
```

Now it should create the file in the current `default-directory`.

It also makes a difference where your cursor is, when executing `C-x C-e`. Put it at the end of the document.

Comment: If I replace custom-file with "test_new_file", the output in the bottom of emacs is "test_new_file". But I can not find the new_file. Or what should I replace it with ? The new file should be in my home folder, right ? Or somewhere else ?

Comment: The text you are asking it to write to the file is empty: `""`. So you can expect that the file will be empty. You (apparently) asked Emacs to write an empty string to a new file. What do you expect? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The problem is not, that the file is empty (also i did not say that anywhere). The problem is however, that no file at all is created.

Comment: Works for me. Did you use an *absolute* file name? If not, try wrapping your (relative) file name in `expand-file-name`.