# how to create file after c-x c-f in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Most of the time after navigating to my desired I find the file I'm looking for missing, therefore I need to create one, I navigate with `C-x RET C-f`, how do I create a file after this ?

**EDIT** The command I'm using is documented [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieKeyReference) , After typing `C-x RET C-f` I get the following image, now after pressing I enter into Arena/ I wanna create a file now
[image]

Comment: `C-x RET C-f is undefined`  Are you asking about something like?: `M-x write-file`  Or, perhaps creating a file using the external command `touch`?

Comment: Or are you possibly using `ido` or `helm`, or even `dired`?

Comment: Here is a related thread relating to file creation in `dired-mode`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300137/how-to-create-new-file-from-dired-mode

Comment: `C-x C-f` looks for a file. If the file is not there, you can create one by hitting `return`. It will ask you to confirm the new file; if that's what you want hit `return` once more.

Comment: I prefer to use `C-x C-f` to create files over `M-x ! touch...` and the like.  My main problem using this is that if the file name matches another file in a different directory in the current project, the prompt gets redirected there unless I hit return **really** quickly after the confirm message.

Answer (score 0):

As your screenshot is of a `dired` buffer...

I posted an answer to another question with [an analog of `dired-create-directory` (<kbd>+</kbd>) which creates files instead of directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18885461/324105), but otherwise operates the same way.

I've used it myself on numerous occasions, so I think it's useful.